# Blank Mosaico templates

Tags: civimail, extension, mosaico

Just newly installed Mosaico - I did the three extensions in the right order and the correct versions (afaik), but when I try to create a mailing, the templates are not there, just the text/title. There's no way to edit the template, either when creating a new mail or via the Mosaico Templates menu link.

It's also gone super slow - is this related?

I was going to do a screenshot but now the Mailing edit page won't load. No error message, it just displays the Title ('CiviCRM') and a blank page. Is this related? When I disable just the Mosaico extension, the speed almost returns to normal and the normal 'traditional' mailing component works as normal.

Comment: Just wondering if you are you getting any useful error messages in the browser console or in the PHP error log?

Comment: I've seen this problem updating a CiviCRM database from a production site to a dev site

Answer (score 1):

Turning off Asset Caching fixed this issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar thing after upgrading CiviCRM from 4.7.30 to 4.7.31, I have as well all the Mosaico templates now blank !
This affect all the archive.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably permission thing with the webserver.  We're running nginx and in the nginx logs we were getting access forbidden by rule for this.  There are other extensions in the same directory but I guess they don't need the same level of access.